# Can't find logiq mysql request SELECT ... IN

Tags: mysql, request

I have a table "Posts_Tags" with 2 fields.

```
post_id  tag_id
1          1
1          4
1          9
2          1
2          4
2          7
3          2
3          4
```

A table "Tags" with 3 types

```
tag_id    type       name
1         geoloc     Paris
2         geloc      Rome
3         geoloc     London
4         paint      Abby
5         paint      Martin
6         paint      Dupont
7         designer   Paulo
8         designer   Stefy
9         designer   Michel
```

I would like to get the post_id linked to several tags_id.

I have already made a simple request to get all posts ID with the following tags : Paris, Rome.

```
 $arrray_in = array(1, 2); //This array is generated and can contain all Tags Ids, this is example value, maybe can i 10 values or more...
SELECT * FROM posts_tags WHERE tag_id IN($array_in) GROUP BY post_id
```

I would like to be able to get only post_id with the following tags Paris (geoloc) and Abby (paint). This request don't give me the good result (return post_id : 1, 2, 3 and i want only post_id : 1, 2)

```
$arrray_in = array(1, 2); //This array is generated and can contain all Tags Ids, this is example value, maybe can i 10 values or more...
    SELECT * FROM posts_tags WHERE tag_id IN($array_in) GROUP BY post_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to get the posts that have only those tags:

```
SELECT pt.post_id
FROM posts_tags pt
WHERE pt.tag_id IN(1, 4) 
GROUP BY pt.post_id
having count(distinct pt.tag_id) =2;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c798d/12).

If you want to return more details about the posts, then you canuse:

```
select *
from posts_tags pt1
inner join tags t
  on pt1.tag_id = t.tag_id
  and t.tag_id in (1, 4)
where exists (SELECT pt.post_id
              FROM posts_tags pt
              WHERE pt.tag_id IN(1, 4) 
                and pt1.post_id = pt.post_id
              GROUP BY post_id
              having count(distinct pt.tag_id) =2);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c798d/16)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I have forget to tell, the tags_id could more than 2 in the search condition...
I have update the post.

Comment: You save my life !! Thanks for all and the Fidlle !
I have counted the tag_type contains before my request

Comment: @jlafforgue You are welcome! Please keep in mind that if this answer or any answer to your questions is helpful, then consider accepting it via the checkmark to the left of it. See [How does accepting answers work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).